What was the halachic / ethical basis for Yaakov to listen to his mother to lie to his father?
Yaakov was told by Rivkah to steal the blessings of Eisav and mislead Yitzchok. He went on to do so, and his only concern was that Yitzchok might reveal his identity.
What was the technical justification of this? He is obligated to respect both of his parents. To mislead his father is not against the respect? What is the weight of the command of his mother against speaking falsehood?
I saw that some explanations wanted to say that על פי הדיבור, Rivkah had a nevuah which has some sort of more obligation than regular כיבוד אב ואם, but this is very hard for me to hear. Does not the Rambam say that in order to listen to a navi to "temporary suspend" a mitzvah from the Torah the navi must have some חזקה?

Similar (but not identic) question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118568/evidence-that-yaakov-did-the-right-thing-in-fooling-his-father-to-get-the-bracho

Rashi says בא אחיך במרמה means בחכמה. Sounds like he didn't feel deceived.

Play the long game here. Imagine Esav does get the bracha, and proceeds to do some horrible things. People will look back and say "what a shame that Yitzchak was such a fool and enabled all of this." So Rivka's plan is in Yitzchak's best interests too. We mistake "honor" for "mindlessly obey." (Or in simple halachic terms -- the obligation doesn't apply when it conflicts with a Torah commandment.)

See this answer for times when one should listen to one's mother over one's father, in particular "If one knows one's father doesn't want them to do something but he never said it out loud, and his mother asks him to do it, then they can do it." If you think this answers your question, let me know and I will write it up along with full citations. There are many halachos here that we could consider, including if one's father is "insane", or when his father says to not do something but the mother says do etc.

@Shalom Thank you!  But which Torah commandment do you mean here?

@RabbiKaii Thank you, I think this can be an answer from what it seems to me now. Write please if possible!

Rabbi Slifkin wrote a book about this

Perhaps allowing his father to be tricked by eisav to think he was pious and deserving of the bracha might have been lifne iver and in this case there was no chance to explain how eisav was off so the quickest solution was unfortunately another deception to prevent the regrettable action of giving the bracha to a rasha?

Note that a few commentaries hold that there’s a chance רִבקה shouldn’t have made יעְקב do this. Maybe relevant, maybe not.

If I were Yaacov in that situation*, and I had to think on my feet, I would consider the Shach s'k 8 on SA YD 240:6, which state that when one is given a difficult situation of kibbud av v'em, one is allowed to do as they see as the best course of action. The best course of action ultimately preserves the parents' honour, and avoids their embarrassment as much as possible.
Indeed, what a difficult situation it was. On the one hand, Pitchei Teshuva brings up R' Akiva Eiger (Teshuvot, siman 68) that says maybe we should listen to the mother over the father (despite ibid. 240:18 "listen to father over mother" based on Kiddishin 31a, see Beur HaGolah) in this case, because maybe this involves a mitzva1. Rabbi Akiva Eiger quotes the Taz and overall this is also very relevant and much about honouring a father who does something "wrong" can be applied here, where he was about to give Yaacov's brachot to Esav.
The sensitivity towards how to handle complex situations is captured in the Aruch Hashulchan here, and the Ben Ish Chai Shana Bet Shoftim2, helping one factor embarrassment, emotional and moral sensitivity towards Yitzchak, his mother, and the situation, especially in the future when, as Shalom said in this comment, people will blame Yitzchak for giving the brachot to Esav.
Yaacov likely settled on the Marachei Leiv 2 Derush 73; Shaarei Ezra Y.D. 20; Kneses Hagedola 240:29; Maharshach 1:137 et al.3, which explain that one should listen to one's mother over one's father if she asks you to do something explicitly, but he didn't forbid it explicitly, in the very little time he had to think, and followed his mother. He could always blame the Shach for instructing that one should do as he pleased in these hard situations, in case it turned out he was wrong. From the overall response from commentaries on the Torah, it seems like he made the right decision though!

* This is all just theorising on my behalf of course. Thank goodness I am not actually Yaacov Avinu, because what a tough decision indeed it is, as stated. We don't wish upon ourselves the tests of our forefathers, not to mention the standards they were held to. Especially given the fact that, as we can see, bein adam lechavero (even the loftiest one that is included on the bein adam laMakom side of the luchot), involve halachot, like the Shach above, which basically say:

"do as you see fit and try your best (and make sure to learn and absorb as much Torah as possible for any chance at success!), because these situations are way too important, but also too hard and complex to provide a neat set of rules to cover everything"


1. Ensuring blessing for the Jewish people is in the Torah's interest, at least, which also is backed up by the spirit of SA YD 240:17 "do not honour requests to break the Torah", see this Shulchan Aruch Harav, and footnote 10: "Shut Rav Akiva Eiger 1:68 writes that in such a case he may precede whoever he wishes; Yad Eliyahu 1:40 rules that in such a case he must precede his mother; Chazon Ish Y.D. 149:6; Encyclopedia Talmudit ibid footnotes 655-656"
2. Especially 10 in particular, and this Taz.
3. Quoted in the same Shulchan Aruch Harav, footnote 18. See also this answer, and source.

Thank you, Boruch Hashem, I am glad I asked the question to trigger you to collect such a nice set of relevant sources!

I've just found that Rav Osher Weiss had a very similar question and detailed analysis, alatt exactly in the same topic.
https://minchasasher.com/shiur/toldot-bereishit-shiurim/5776-midvar-sheker-tirchak/
Here he basically concludes that מדבר שקר תרחק is not an absolute Torah prohibition, rather, a virtue that can be and often indeed is overridden by other considerations.
(The irony of this all is that on the other end we have כיבוד אב ואם about which Shulchan Aruch YD 240:15 says that is overridden virtually by anything else, even rabbinic prohibition.)
